# How to format unstrctured text file?

Tags: powershell

```
1111    700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
        700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
        700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
        700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
2211    700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
        700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
        700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
        700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
3311    700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
        700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
        700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
        700000000000c940  FIBRE  FA-11G:1,FA-12G:1
```

How do I print this on same line using powershell ?

```
1111 700000000000c940 700000000000c940 700000000000c940 700000000000c940.
2211 700000000000c940 700000000000c940 700000000000c940 700000000000c940.
3311 700000000000c940 700000000000c940 700000000000c940 700000000000c940.
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have PowerShell v3 try this one-liner:

```
(Get-Content file.txt -Raw) -replace '(?<=\w{16}\s).+' -replace '(?<= ) |\r?\n\s+'
```

Comment: I currently dont have access to powershell 3 but I will download it today and will run it

Comment: This was perfect, worked perfectly. Thanks a ton. If you could be kind enough to just explain what you did here so I could learn a bit . and same thing if I have to do in powershell 2 how do i do this ?

Comment: Found a way to do it in V2 . [io.file]::readalltext("d:\ps\test.txt") -replace '(?<=\w{16}\s).+' -replace '(?<= ) |\r?\n\s+' However I still need to understand the two replace and what exactly they do.

Answer (score 0):

Now it makes a little more sense. Behold my favourite tool for parsing text `switch -regex`:

```
switch -regex -file foo.txt {
    '^(\d+)\s+(\S+)' {
        if ($s) { $s }
        $s = "$($Matches[1]) $($Matches[2])"
    }
    '^\s+(\S+)' { $s += " $($Matches[1])" }
}
if ($s) { $s }
```

Comment: the number of lines just keep on repeating , example .

Comment: I need the output to look like,

Comment: It works for few lines and then it doesnt for some and it never runs till the end of file . Example below

Comment: I dont understand what does if ($s) { $s } this line do ?

Comment: This code works by parsing the input file line by line and constructing a result line from several input lines. This temporary result is stored in `$s` and the line you stumbled over is just there to output the final line after the file has been processed completely.